# How to lay background image on top my CSS gradient

Tags: css, background-image, gradient

Having a hard time getting my background image to lay up top my CSS gradient.This is what I have but when I open it on my mobile phone the image is behind the gradient background. THis is being used on mobile devices, latest versions of IOS and Android.

```
body {
background-size:cover;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(20,36,130) 44%, rgb(255,255,255) 67%, rgb(7,22,137) 26%), url(main_BG.png);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(20,36,130) 44%, rgb(255,255,255) 67%, rgb(7,22,137) 26%), url(main_BG.png);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(20,36,130) 44%, rgb(255,255,255) 67%, rgb(7,22,137) 26%), url(main_BG.png);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(20,36,130) 44%, rgb(255,255,255) 67%, rgb(7,22,137) 26%),url(main_BG.png);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(20,36,130) 44%, rgb(255,255,255) 67%, rgb(7,22,137) 26%),url(main_BG.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.44, rgb(20,36,130)),
    color-stop(0.67, rgb(255,255,255)),
    color-stop(0.26, rgb(7,22,137)),url(main_BG.png);
    );
}
```

Comment: can you past you code on "http://jsfiddle.net/" or give link on work site

Answer (score 0):

Just putting the image URL first should do the trick.

```
background-image:url(main_BG.png), linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(20,36,130) 44%, 
rgb(255,255,255) 67%, rgb(7,22,137) 26%);
```